# How do I get words of certain length?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, awk

Supppose I have data like this:

```
this
is 
ttttaaaaa
aaattt
```

The expected output that I am looking for is:

```
is 
ttttaaaaa
```

I am using awk. This is the *idea*:

```bash
awk 'length <= 4 && length >= 8'
```

But that does not work. How can this be done?

Comment: I think you mean "or" `||`, not "and" `&&`.

Comment: Aren't `length <= 4 && length >= 8` contradictory? I wouldn't expect any output. Did you mean `length >= 4 && length <= 8` or `length <= 4 || length >= 8`?

Comment: and didn't show up any result so, I will go with or because it is showing the result

Comment: Does it have to be awk?  `grep` does this just fine with a RegEx (and I'm sure RegEx experts can make mine smaller):  `printf "this\nis\nttttaaaaa\naaattt" | grep -E ^\(.\{0,3\}\|.\{9,\}\)$`

Answer (score 2):

You need to use OR instead of AND

Try this:

```
cat file.txt | awk 'length($0) < 4 || length($0) > 8'
```

It will take file.txt as input and print all lines with length less than 4 or greater than 8.

Comment: Would you be willing to explain in your answer why the OP conditions don't work?

Comment: We do not need `cat` in this case: `awk 'length($0) < 4 || length($0) > 8' file.txt`

Comment: Can also be expressed as `awk '!(4 <= length && length <= 8)'` -- i.e. not between 4 and 8.